# How to force some customer to be serviced by a specific vehicle in VRP examples of the OptaPlanner?

Tags: drools, optaplanner, drools-planner

In the VRP examples of Optaplanner, I would like to force some customer to be serviced by a specific vehicle in VRP.

How to do this? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways. The easiest is probably just to add a hard constraint

```
when
    Customer(forcedVehicleIsNotVehicle == true)
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraint...
end

class Customer {

    public boolean isForcedVehicleIsNotVehicle() {
         return forcedVehicle != null
              && vehicle != null && forcedVehicle != vehicle;
    }

}
```